# configuration.getValue or configuration.getsection always returns null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to .Net Core and trying to get a value from the `appsettings.json` file but I have missed something very basic. Please let me know what I have done wrong... 
Here is the code...

**Program.cs**

```
 WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
 .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
 {
      config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
 })
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<EmailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));
}
```

**Web API Controller**

```
private readonly IConfiguration config;

public EmailController(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    if (configuration != null)
    {
        config = configuration;
    }
}
```

**Action Method**

```
var emailTemplatesRelativePath = config.GetSection("EmailSettings");
var email = config.GetValue<string>("Email");
```

Both the above lines are returning null values for both `GetSection` and `GetValue`

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "FCRContext": "server=xxx;database=xxx;user id=xxx;password=xxx"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "EmailSettings": {
    "EmailTemplatesPath": "EmailTemplates"
  },
  "Email": "aa@aa.com"
}
```

Comment: You usually initialize IConfiguration in `Startup.cs`; not in `Program.cs`. If you are getting null the way you describe, something is wrong there. Please show `Startup.cs`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2 I am following this. I tried **Options Pattern** as well, but it didn't work...

Comment: .Net Core 2.2 and using IIS Express for now..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When hosting [in-process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2#in-process-hosting-model) inside of IIS (or IIS Express), `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` will return a different path to that which is returned when running [out-of-process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2#out-of-process-hosting-model). Up until ASP.NET Core 2.1, IIS-based hosting was always out-of-process, but ASP.NET Core 2.2 introduces the ability to run in-process (which is the default when creating a new project).

When running out-of-process, `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` will return the path to your ASP.NET Core application itself, whereas when running in-process, it will return the path to IIS (or IIS Express, e.g. "C:\Program Files\IIS Express").

From your question, the relevant code is this:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
    {
        config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
    })
```

Here, before you make a call to [`SetBasePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileconfigurationextensions.setbasepath?view=aspnetcore-2.1), the `IConfigurationBuilder` has already been set up to use the correct path. Your call itself is overriding this path, setting it to e.g. "C:\Program Files\IIS Express". With this *overridden* base-path, your `appsettings.json` et al files are no longer found, as they do not live in e.g. "C:\Program Files\IIS Express", and so no configuration is loaded from these files.

The solution is simply to remove your call to `ConfigureAppConfiguration` so that the base-path does not get overridden. I realise you've already discovered this, but I wanted to make sure you had an explanation as to what was going wrong here.

Comment: Are there any implications when deploying this to 1) older versions of IIS or 2) latest versions of IIS?  If we have "in-process" set for our project, do we just never use config.SetBasePath even though its in the project when it's created?  If so, I guess its just MS hasn't updated the template for it.

Answer (score 7):

Accessing the configuration in the Controller works a little different than in the Startup.cs. I did this a while back, just follow these steps:

> Nuget: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder

Put all the Configuration you want to access in your Controller into one Section, e.g. "EmailSettings":

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "EmailSettings": {
    "EmailTemplatesPath": "EmailTemplates",
    "Email": "aa@aa.com"
  }
}
```

Then Create a Class in your Web API Project called `EmailSettings.cs` :

**EmailSettings.cs**

```
public class EmailSettings
{
    public string EmailTemplatesPath { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Then bind your Config values to an Instance of the `EmailSettings` Class in `Startup.cs` and add that Object to the Dependency Injection Container:

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    EmailSettings emailSettings = new EmailSettings();
    Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings").Bind(emailSettings);
    services.AddSingleton(emailSettings);
}
```

Now you can request your Configuration in the Api Controller by simply adding it to the Constructor like this:

**Web API Controller**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    EmailSettings _emailSettings;

    public ValuesController(EmailSettings emailSettings)
    {
        _emailSettings = emailSettings;
    }
....
}
```

Just tried this again in my current Project (.NET Core 2.2 Web Api) and it worked. I put a Breakpoint in the ValuesController Constructor and the _emailSettings Object contained the values from the `appsettings.json` file. You should be able to just Copy & Paste this! Have fun! :)

Comment: No, The two code lines are there to show that both the `GetSection` and the `GetValue` are returning no values.

Comment: Updated to work in Controllers. I tested it myself, just give it a try :)

Answer (score 3):

You made a simple mistake and forgot to add "Email" into "EmailSettings". Update your json as shown below and get the Email with `config.GetSection("EmailSettings")["Email"];`

```
"EmailSettings": {
    "EmailTemplatesPath": "EmailTemplates",
    "Email": "aa@aa.com"
  },
```

Hope this solves your problem.

**Edit:**

If you wanna get those values from appsettings to anything other than startup, you should load those config values into a settings class and then inject appropiate IOptions instance to the method constructor in which you want to use those settings. To do so, please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53904527/5198054).

Comment: Those are two separate statements suggesting that none of them are returning any value.

Comment: Can you see my answer on this link and get those values from appsetting.json via settings class and inject it to the controller with IOptions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53904527/5198054

Answer (score 1):

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
             .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
        {
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
    }
```

**Controller Class**

[image]

You need to use Bind() method to get the value from section.

```
EmailSetting option = new EmailSetting();
            //You need to bind the section with data model, 
            //it will automatically map config key to property of model having same name
            config.GetSection("EmailSettings").Bind(option);

            //Alternative to this you can read nested key using below syntax
            var emailTemplatesPath = config["EmailSettings:EmailTemplatesPath"];
            var emailInEmailSettings = config["EmailSettings:Email"];
            // If email key is not nested then you can access it as below
            var email = config.GetValue<string>("EmailOutside");
```

Email Setting Model:- (Property name should match with config Key)

```
public class EmailSetting
    {
        public string EmailTemplatesPath { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

Appsetting.json:-

```
    {
       "AllowedHosts": "*",
        "EmailSettings": {
            "EmailTemplatesPath": "EmailTemplates",
            "Email": "aa@aa.com"
          },
          "EmailOutside": "aa@aa.com"
        }
```

Comment: This `config["EmailSettings:EmailTemplatesPath"]` still returns `null`.

Comment: and according to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.bind?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.Bind);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=aspnetcore-2.1 Bind is not available in `.Net Core 2.2`

Comment: Please try to create simple MVC project with one controller to read config file. I have updated answer and added the code sample in it. try to keep this dummy project very simple, do not add any middle ware in pipeline except MVC.

Comment: Thanks. That helped. I created an empty application and that was returning the configuration values correctly. Then I compared the two `program.cs`, the problem was this line that I had to 

    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, 
    {
        config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
    })

Comment: Don't know why that is the problem. The MSDN says that I need to add that... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: I tried with and without ConfigureAppConfiguration().In  both cases code were working fine.

Answer (score 1):

While others have solved this problem, if you want to leave your startup services code as is, just change your Web API controller to the following:

```
private readonly EmailSettings _emailSettings;

public EmailController(IOptions<EmailSettings> emailSettings)
{
    _emailSettings = emailSettings.Value;
}
```

The emphasis is on the **.Value**. That's why your code is returning null. I would also suggest changing program.cs back to it's default. And to use this in an action method, just do the following:

```
_email.settings.EmailTemplatesPath
```

One last thing - make sure your EmailSettings class structure is the exact same as your json.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```cs
services.Configure<EmailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));
services.AddTransient(p => p.GetRequiredService<IOptions<EmailSettings>>().Value);
```

and initialize EmailSettings object via constructor DI.